# How do I write the output of nginx -t (config test) to a file?

Tags: linux, nginx

Running `nginx -t` will test the configuration for correct syntax and will output a message describing the error if there is one or will say that syntax is ok.

I want to have that output written to a file and I tried:

```
nginx -t > test.txt
```

This command is creating my `text.txt` file without any content. How can I get that output in a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nginx write this to `stderr`, not to `stdout`. Use `nginx -t 2> text.txt`

Comment: But why does nginx write the successful `syntax is ok` to the `stderr`, that doesn't make sense.